# How to use Coroutine and when to know data is received?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm

Hey so I want to record all the results from a quiz done by user and present them in Recycler View. To do so, I am using Android Room DB , MVVM Architecture and Coroutines.

The data will flow like `Dao->View Model(and then,through Live Data to UIC).`

I want to implement code using Enum but I dont know how to do it. I want to use a Enum class which will have values ( NEUTRAL, LOADING, AVAILABLE) and all of these will have a
`val list : LiveData<LiveData<ResultFile>>`
Obviously, the main use will be in available.

My question to you is, what to write in View Model, like which corotuine, and what to exactly write in it. How will I know when all the rows from the table are fetched from DB and come into the VM?

The following are the screenshots
[Dao](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ezekn.png)
[Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9LKg.png)

I tried but I dont know when will the data arrive?

Comment: There are many online tutorials walking through how to do this. Maybe you can show us your attempt so we only have to tell you what to fix instead of repeating a whole tutorial back to you.

Comment: Could you link some?

Comment: Look up the Room with a View Android CodeLab.

Comment: [ViewModel] (https://pasteboard.co/m7WtNSGYvKPs.png) The problem (https://pasteboard.co/GG1OoC16Nxyd.png) @Tenfour04

Comment: You need to read and fully understand this page to be able to use Kotlin: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html

Comment: I know what null safety is. I was just asking that how to handle that without changing the other Data class. Anyways, this should work right? [MarsViewModel] (https://pasteboard.co/VtSLyQlBswBo.png). I found this at (https://shorturl.at/etEIZ).

Comment: Because this is, in one way the same thing, the request that we are trying to make will take  sometime. So whenever the data is loaded, it would be refected into the livedata and since I am observing that live data, I would know when the data is ready.  @tenfour04

Comment: That last code you posted looks fine to me. The previous code lacks enough context for me to tell what was wrong with it. I didn’t know what was nullable and what was non-nullable. Generally, I avoid nullability wherever possible. For lists and Strings you can represent lack of data with `emptyList()` and `""`.  When receiving nullable data, you can convert it with `orEmpty()`. Side note, the use of `ArrayList()` here is a slight code smell that suggests to me that your LiveData type might be a MutableList or ArrayList instead of read-only List, which is inviting bugs.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Okay. So Just to confirm. In the last code, assuming the network request takes time, lets say 3 seconds. And when it does, the value will be posted, which I will know since I will be using live data. Then, would the try block go sequentially. Excuse me, I am kinda of new to this concurrency control thing, but would the control flow wait 3 seconds for the request to go to MapsApiStatus.DONE or would it be like, since the network request will run on background thread, the MapsApiStatus.DONE would execute before the value comes from Network Request?

Comment: It depends how that `getProperties()` function is defined. If it returns a Call, it’s asynchronous and you should call `await()` on it to wait for it before the code continues. Or you could define it as a suspend function that doesn’t return a Call so you can just directly call it. If it doesn’t return a Call and it’s not marked `suspend`, then it is blocking and you need to wrap the call in `withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { }` to safely use it.

Comment: @Tenfour04 [https://pasteboard.co/qPojJxYPauiM.png ]

Comment: @Tenfour04 like in this, [ https://pasteboard.co/IU7wq85rXo5O.png ] , the doExpWork() takes min 1.5 Seconds. But the app works fine. Why in those 1.5 seconds, the control flow doesnt go to the View.INVISIBLE statement?

Comment: Same was the problem I was having with this, https://pasteboard.co/VtSLyQlBswBo.png, I cannot call await on getProperties, so how can I assure that it will go sequentially like I have coded it and not go like 0th sec - getProperties 1st sec _status.value = MapsAPpiStatus.DONE 3rd Sec getProperties returns value and then the observer is called.

Comment: Because suspend functions are **synchronous** without blocking. That's the primary reason for coroutines--you can write sequential code that doesn't block. By the way, pictures of code are very hard to read. It would be easier to see actual text. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors You don't need to call `await()` if you already defined the function as `suspend`. Awaiting is only necessary when you get a `Call` from Retrofit. `Call` can be considered obsolete in a coroutine-based project.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Since suspend functions are synchronous, before executing the next line, the current line should get the result it has requested. Got it. I had faced the issue non-synchronous code a while back so maybe I confused it with this. Can you suggest me from where I can master from sratch this concurrency control, async sync coroutine topic. I face this a lot and I have to go through it again and again. Could you like give me simple sequential todo list of topics/ Resources I should learn to grasp this topic. @Tenfour04

Comment: Okay. I will use code links next time.

Comment: This is a good overview: https://elizarov.medium.com/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761 You can also read all of Roman Elizarov's other articles on coroutines on the Medium site. He was the lead designer of Kotlin coroutines, and I think some of his explanations never really made it into the official documentation, but he was writing about it on Medium. But be careful, because a few of his articles may be obsolete now. For example,  "Cold flows and hot channels" is outdated because of the introduction of SharedFlow and StateFlow.